# C - explicit integral as a parameter

Tags: c

I am counting approximation of Pi, I have made it to `3,14596`, but I have tried to set integral for counting pi as a parameter when starting program and no result came from it. I tried add when starting program `4/1+x*x` (there should by brackets around `1+x*x`, but compilator sees them as a mistake), and I get it from `args[1`] as a 4 only when I transfered char to int with `itoa()`. Is there any way how to pass it to application for computing? This is the line in my program:

```
float sum, integral;
integral=4/(1+x*x);
sum=sum+integral;
```

And I have it in for loop. In this case it counts great, but how to incorporate theese parameter?I have thought of some specific char replacement (I would replace X for an actual value), but is it possible?

Comment: @Hmyzak: what are the declarations for `integral` and `sum`?

Comment: sorry, didn't mention, both are floats

Comment: @Hmyzak: and `x` us a `float` too? Either way, you'll probably want a `double` for improved precision, given the nature of the task.

Comment: Yea, they are 'double' too, but still I am stuck in a giving integral as a parameter

Comment: @Hmyzak: but where does the integer come in? Your code snippet only references three variables and you say all of them are floats.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED see my answer below, he wants to give the formula used as integral as a parameter to the program and make something like `eval` of interpreted languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the formula as argument of your program. Your `arg[1]` parameter is a string, when you call `atoi` you make only the conversion of the numbers up to the first nun numeric character, so in your case it converted the '4' character of your string `"4/1+x*x"` and stopped conversion at the '/'.

If you want to use the formula, you have to write an interpreter that analyzes the string, builds an evaluation tree and execute by replacing the values of the variables. Something quite complicated, probably not under several hundred lines of code. 
It's probably easier to use the formula in the source code and recompile the program accordingly. If it's not possible, change to an interpreted language like perl, python, javascript which implement the `eval` function.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so... and what about scanning what user writes? Can scanf() be the solution?

Comment: Oooh, so he was trying to pass a function? Didn't get that :)

Comment: @Hmyzak: the most straightforward (and IMO easiest) solution would be to embed Lua and interpret the parameter as a Lua chunk.

Comment: No, you need an `eval` function, which doesn't exist in compiled languages. It's part of the compiler and isn't included in the runtime. There might be libraries that implement such evaluators but I don't know them so you will have to search yourself for it. I just googled and found this interesting page with explanations and library http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/dynamicformula.aspx

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED - so Lua chunk is the solution you say?

Comment: @tristopia - thanks I will look on it, hope I will be able to put there variable x instead of numbers

Comment: @Hmyzak: of course you still need to *link* to Lua. But yes, if tristopia got you right, this would be what you want.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED and do you know some links, where can I lear about Lua? I have no experiences in it... thanks

Comment: @Hmyzak: http://lua.org - it comes under the very lenient MIT license and uses double as its only numerical type by default. You can read the code of the very simplistic Lua command line interpreter to get started quickly with your particular problem, since the problems are similar.